# Show logged-in users? [userfrosting]

Tags: userfrosting

How big of a task is it to be able to show users who are logged in, at least in the root/admin panel?

Thank you

[userfrosting 0.3.1]

Comment: Start by defining what "logged in" means exactly in the context of a stateless PHP application.

Comment: I suppose this requires sessions to be registered in the database, and there is no mechanism for that in current UF implementation? Correct?

Comment: I have no idea about UF, but in general: if a user logged in, browsed your pages for a few minutes, then closes the browser, then later returns while probably still being logged in… does the time in which their browser was closed count as "logged in"?

Comment: There are ways to handle those,... some of which come to mind:  session time outs, timestamp of last activity etc. To answer your question: yes, a simple performant way is to keep user as "logged-in" until session times out (last user activity beyond threshold).

Comment: This question is too broad for SO.  This is better discussed in [chat](https://chat.userfrosting.com).  Actually, if you search the chat logs, you can see a discussion we had about this feature before.  You can also open a [feature request](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22feature+request%22) if you think this would be a good core feature for UF.